# INFO: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is ignored

Tags: javascript, android

i was trying to build my application , and its show me error

INFO: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Remove Build Tools version and sync project
Affected Modules: LibraryRateMe

**my build.grandle ( Module LibraryRateMe )**

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    resourcePrefix "rateme__"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
    }
}
// Used to push in maven
apply from: '../maven_push.gradle'
```

**Build Grandle ( Module:app )**

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sqstudio.sqtv"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : '146000be-04ec-4fd0-8d5e-7ed919604216',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-beta01'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05'


    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'                  // ripple effect

    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    // retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'

    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.5'
    implementation 'com.hootsuite.android:nachos:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.7.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.7.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.7.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-rtmp:2.7.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-cast:2.7.3'
    implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:master-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.cast.companionlibrary:ccl:2.8.4'

    implementation 'com.github.ixiDev:GDPRChecker:v0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7'


    implementation project(':LibraryRateMe')

    implementation 'com.androidsx:rate-me:4.0.3'


}
```

**Grandle Project Android**

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Help Please

Comment: The message form Android Studio/Gradle says it all - what is you actual question? Anyway it is just an info message you don't need to do anything.

Comment: yeah but when i change the version , its show me another errors